# Carbon divide records into weeks and months

Tags: php, laravel

I have a record where I am getting data with timestamps (created_at, updated_at) for last 4 months. Next, I want to divide this data into week wise and month wise (last 4 weeks and last 4 months.)

What I am trying is to manually create variables for each months and then write if logic to enter data into each month. Is there any function that already does it?

```
    // for student population - Last 4 months data
    $from = Carbon::now()->subMonth(4);

    $to = Carbon::now(); 

    $invoice =invoice::where('instructor_id', '=', $id)
    ->whereBetween('created_at',[$from,$to])->get();

    $week_1=$week_2=$week_3=$week_4=$month_1=$month_2=$month_3=$month_4=[];

    // write if logic and enter data for each week separately
```

Comment: You can use collection method [whereBetween](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-wherebetween) to filter data in your $invoice collection for each week and month in a similar fashion that you retrieve it from the database.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no `function that already does it`, afaik, in Eloquent or Carbon.

I would suggest looping through the Eloquent Collection.

Here is a hint for you :

```
$from = Carbon::now()->subMonth(4);
$to = Carbon::now(); 

$invoices = invoice::where('instructor_id', '=', $id)->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->get();

// ...

$invoicesLastWeek = $invoices->whereBetween('created_at', [
        Carbon::now()->subWeeks(1)->startOfWeek(),
        Carbon::now()->subWeeks(1)->endOfWeek()
    ]);

// ...

$invoicesTwoMonthsAgo = $invoices->whereBetween('created_at', [
    Carbon::now()->subMonths(2)->startOfMonth()),
    Carbon::now()->subMonths(2)->endOfMonth()
]);

// ...
```

I would loop and increment parameters for `->subWeeks($i)->` and `->subMonths($i)->`, and populate the needed variables.

I would start setting each `week` vars first, so that I can pop out of the Collection all invoices in that range (for performance). Then for each `month` vars, I would add `weekN + weekN+1 + weekN+2 + weekN+3` vars (and pop them out of the Collection as well, so that I loop faster on a Collection that is getting smaller everytime).